# Error in Exchange Management Console: The specified domain either does not exist or cannot be contacted

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I'm currently in the process of trying to get my new exchange server up and running. As far as I could tell the installation went fine, It completed, Ran updates, and restarted. However once the server rebooted I attempted to login to the EMC and was faced with this error

```
Initialization failed

The following error occurred while searching for the on-premises Exchange server.

Exception calling "GetComputerSite" with "0" argument(s): "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted." 

"It was running the command 'Discover-ExchangeServer -UseWIA $true -SuppressError $true -CurrentVersion 'Version 14.1 (Build 218.15)".
```

This is an installation of Exchange 2010 SP1 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Machine. I can provide any additional details required to solve this problem.

Things I have Tried:

- Restarting WinRM service
- Restarting Exchange App Pools
- Connecting Via Powershell (Same Error)

Things I think it could be:

- an issue with IIS not being configured properly.
- An issue with DNS.
- Exchange somehow might actually have the wrong domain?
- My install may have not gone as fine as I planned/Thought (when does anything)

I am currently in mission critical mode as our current exchange 2007 system is on its last legs. Any suggestions or assistance would be greatly appreciated. If I have to remove the install and start it from scratch I will. I'm very much prepared to pull an all nighter to get this accomplished.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd deploy Exchange Server 2010?

Comment: Honestly, Its because the overall cost to upgrade to Exchange 2016 (New Office versions, Exchange 2016 LIC, Exchange 2016 Cals etc.)was over 40K and management wouldn't pony up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" Exchange 2010 SP1 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 "

That is an unsupported combination. For Windows 2012 R2 support you need to be on Exchange 2010 SP3.

Why did you install Exchange 2010 SP1?

Since Exchange 2007 all service packs have been the complete product.

If you had downloaded Exchange 2010 SP3, then the latest rollup and put it in to the Updates directory, then it would have installed both. That only works for a fresh installation, not an update.

Install SP3, then the rollup and reboot the server. Check again.

Comment: Unfortunately I found this out far too late. The upgrade was rushed and we didn't do the proper research ahead of time. We have done the appropriate research now and have devised a new plan. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run dcdiag and also check if you can access the sysvol shares from the exchange server. It sounds like dns issue indeed but it can also be an ad replication issue.

Comment: I will agree with Sembee, I was sure you were installing the Exchange 2010 SP3. Update to the latest exchange version and check the Exchange Server Supportability Matrix for AD Support Level as well  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx